# Upload file to s3 with php

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I use php to upload file in s3, my codes work properly however when file selects to upload is very heavy like 4 MB operation fails and i have this error :

> `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not exist.1469625998.pdf136D99DB27E5B57FE6UXAbj45afkoAlfysDm2+EPhBqHOhwc64gaG1w/b1AXAsfhnF7qwlankwuflh+ZO1sf/JBe6tA=

But when file is about 1.3 MB, upload success.
below is my codes :

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 include('s3folder/s3_config.php');
 $s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

I'm wondering why any size of file can't be uploaded since i don't specify any size file like **if($size<(1024*1024))** !

Comment: Check your php `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` ini settings. I think it is capped to a size lower than 4 MB.

Comment: my website is hosted in amazon aws, i don't know how to do this..

Comment: Create a php file with contents `<?php phpinfo();`. Upload it to your aws server and open the url in your browser. It will show you all the php settings.

Comment: I just did what you asked me here what i find :post_max_size :32M /  upload_max_filesize : 2M, how can i change 2M so that i can upload file with size more than 2M ? thanks

Comment: please help  so i'm waiting for your answer eagerly ...

Answer (score 0):

Download script [here](https://www.box.com/s/zoan4lum4jlyd46ysf8p) which contain 4 files

- S3.php //Amazon S3 library file
- s3_config.php //Key configuration file
- image_check.php //File validator
- index.php

**s3_config.php**

```
<?php
// Bucket Name
$bucket="BucketName";
if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');

//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'ACCESS_KEY');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'ACCESS_Secret_KEY');

$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$s3->putBucket($bucket, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
?>
```

**index.php**
The file contains PHP and HTML code to submit form.

```
<?php
include('image_check.php'); // getExtension Method
$msg='';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$ext = getExtension($name);

if(strlen($name) > 0)
{
// File format validation
if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
{
// File size validation
if($size<(1024*1024))
{
include('s3_config.php');
//Rename image name. 
$actual_image_name = time().".".$ext;

if($s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $actual_image_name,         S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) )
{
$msg = "S3 Upload Successful."; 
$s3file='http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$actual_image_name;
echo "<img src='$s3file'/>";
echo 'S3 File URL:'.$s3file;
}
else
$msg = "S3 Upload Fail.";

}
else
$msg = "Image size Max 1 MB";

}
else
$msg = "Invalid file, please upload image file.";

}
else
$msg = "Please select image file.";

}
?>

//HTML Code
<form action="" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload image file here
<input type='file' name='file'/> <input type='submit' value='Upload Image'/>
<?php echo $msg; ?>
</form>
```

Create a bucket and right click select properties, add permission select Everyone enable check list box.

**image_check.php**
This file help you to get file extension.

```
<?php
function getExtension($str) 
{
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}
//Here you can add valid file extensions. 
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif","bmp","jpeg","PNG","JPG","JPEG","GIF","BMP");
?>
```

Comment: this is typically the files i'm using, i made some changes, like store the $s3file in table and other post variable from a form. Every think work but if file size is about 4MB, it fails to store it in s3.